# Socket.io xdomain https flashsockets

Tags: node.js, cross-domain, socket.io, flashsocket

Is it possible to have a secure flashsocket connection with a XDomain socket.io app? On the socket.io-client I see the following comment:

```
* The FlashSocket transport. This is a API wrapper for the HTML5 WebSocket
* specification. It uses a .swf file to communicate with the server. If you want
* to serve the .swf file from a other server than where the Socket.IO script is
* coming from you need to use the insecure version of the .swf. More information
* about this can be found on the github page.
```

but cant find the spot on the github page that talks about why it's not possible to use https, xdomain flashsockets with socket.io. I'm using flashsockets for older IE... Seems more reliable than other transports.

On my app, the `js` is served from a subdomain of my domain on server `X`, and the `.swf` would be server from another server, on a different subdomain of the same domain:

```
script is served from sub1.mydomain.com on server X

flash is served and connects to sub2.mydomain.com on server Y (holds socket.io server)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for the flash policy settings if you are mixing secure configuration and flash transports. There are a variety of ways that using flash can make a socket.io deployment more complicated.

Comment: Hi Hdrerms, could you elaborate? Is it possible to acheive XDomain with flash using SSL? Or is it not possible and that's why when socket.io detects Xdomain it automatically uses the "Incesure" version?